# Android Virtual Device(AVD) problem in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu-11.04, std

When i try to create a new Android Virtual Device(AVD) on Ubuntu 11.04, i get this error:
"Error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory. Yes, the library file is in its right place /usr/lib :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this problem using Ubuntu 11.04 x64, the error was fixed by installing lib32stdc++6, ia32-libs, and lib32ncursesw5

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
yum install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 glibc.i686
```

and then try again.

It's a 64 bit install I'm guessing.

Comment: nope, it didn't find any such packages....:( yeah, this ubuntu is x64, n there's no SDK for linux in x64...

Comment: i've zeroed it down.. prob is with /android-sdk/tools/mksdcard. i can create a AVD without an sd card

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878445/ubuntu-error-failed-to-create-the-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.10, the ia32-libs package is no more present. Execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

The second shall install all its dependencies and resolve the compiling problems. The dependencies are:

```
gcc-4.8-base:i386 libc6:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 
libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386
libgcc1:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libllvm3.3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 
libstdc++6:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 zlib1g:i386
```