# Failed to get the adb version... No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, adb

I'm running Eclipse 4.2.1 on ubuntu 12.10 and I'm busy installing the Android plugins for Eclipse. So far everything has gone well, I've installed the ADT plugin and all that but now I'm at that stage where (after eclipse has restarted) I have to point Eclipse to the directory I have installed the android SDK to...

The sdk being installed here:

> /opt/android-sdk-linux

But I get the following error message pop up:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this would happen anyone?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, the issue was that I was running a 64bit system (Should've mentioned that). You can find the solution here: [Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine/10473415#10473415)

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you! I was stuck trying to get Cordova set up on by 64-bit OS and this saved me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools and validate that adb is in there?  If you just now downloaded the SDK, recent releases might not come with all the tools so you need to run the SDK manager to download the things you need.  From /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools you can execute "./android sdk" which will start the Android SDK manager and you can download the tools and platform tools (it should the item at the top of the list under the tools folder)

Comment: Hey David, yep I did check, adb is most certainly under platform tools. Also like I mentioned to BenjiWiebe, I have installed platform tools and some other platforms like 4.2, 4.1 etc. etc.

Comment: Hi Dean.  Does adb have executable permissions on your machine?

Comment: Yes full permissions (777), read, write and execute. Interesting point though: I can launch my sdk manager and emulator creator from my Eclipse toolbar. Would this even be possible if eclipse couldn't access my ADB properly?

Comment: Normally the whole plugin doesn't even work if the SDK isn't installed properly. Maybe try restarting eclipse? If you can do that, and adb is in your PATH, then I don't know why ADT can't find it

Comment: I see... I tried restarting eclipse, and that didn't do anything. But I haven't set the adb in my PATH environment variable. I'll give that a shot..

Comment: I think I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878445/ubuntu-error-failed-to-create-the-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

Have you already run `android sdk` and installed Android platform tools? If so, I don't know what's going on. If you have not done that yet, then that is your problem. (`android sdk` is the Android SDK manager.)

Comment: Yep I have, I've run it straight from terminal of course, but yes I have. SDK Manager it's called, installed platform-tools and some other platforms like Jelly bean and Ice cream sandwich and whotnot.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 64bit machine you should try answer by @robbin chander:

> On Linux you need to install IA32 library Because Linux 64-bit ADT
>   bundle comes with a 32 Bit adb under
>   adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb ... This is also a problem
>   under other distributions, e.g. Fedora 17

and try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```