# Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder in linux fedora?

Tags: android, linux, fedora

I have copied **android-sdk-linux** folder from one PC to another PC, and installed Eclipse and Set appropriate paths (both tools and Platform-tools) but I cannot create any avd.

When I try to create new avd from Android Virtual Device Manager, it only show this error message in console when I click new avd.

`[2012-05-29 23:29:27 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.`

`[2012-05-29 23:29:27 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.`

I put my android-sdk-linux folder in /home/nagarjuna/Eclipse/android-sdk-linux

Comment: Verify that you have write permissions on sdk_installation_directory/tools and
/home/username/.android/avd. Otherwise, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

AVD makes use of the mksdcard utility which requires extra dependencies not provided in Fedora by default.

32-bit Android SDK requires:

```
yum install glibc.i686 zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686 ncurses-libs.i686
```

64-bit Android SDK requires:

```
yum install glibc zlib zlib.i686 libstdc++ ncurses-libs mesa-libGL-devel adb
```

Comment: I'm running a 64-bit Fedora 21 LXDE spin with Android Studio 1.1. The second yum line worked for me with the addition of libgcc.i686. In other words, run: `yum install glibc zlib zlib.i686 libstdc++ ncurses-libs mesa-libGL-devel adb libgcc.i686`.
Thanks Christian!

Comment: Confirmed on Fedora 25 x86_64. You'll need to install `libgcc.i686` too

Answer (score 0):

I also tried all the answers given in this link [Ubuntu - Error: Failed to create the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878445/ubuntu-error-failed-to-create-the-sd-card)

Try moving the android sdk folder to home folder. It works.

Answer (score 0):

To install the required 32bit packages manually on 64bit CentOS7.1:

```
# rpm -ivh --force nss-softokn-freebl-3.28.3-6.el7.i686.rpm glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh ncurses-base-5.9-13.20130511.el7.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh zlib-1.2.7-17.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh ncurses-libs-5.9-13.20130511.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh ncurses-devel-5.9-13.20130511.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libXau-1.0.8-2.1.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libxcb-1.12-1.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libXrender-0.9.10-1.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libXext-1.3.3-3.el7.i686.rpm
# rpm -ivh libXrandr-1.5.1-2.el7.i686.rpm
```

(scenario: packages is ok but repomd.xml is corrupted in the iso to build local yum repository  and don't have internet)

Answer (score -2):

Just terminal this:

```
chmod -R 777 /home
```