# aapt not found under the right path

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

I just updated ADT, than the SDK and now I have in only one project the issue, that my aapt isn't found

```
Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at /opt/android/platform-tools/aapt
```

The path is correct, I checked twice and more times.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 martin martin 3,5M 2010-12-08 10:41 /opt/android/platform-tools/aapt
```

I can start aapt via console, the permissions are 777, I restarted eclipse, closed/reopened the project, restarted adb and finally my Ubuntu.

Some ideas why this might happen only at one project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine)

Comment: @jk2K no it is not but thanks for waking up a 6 year old question. It was a caching issue (you would have seen it if you would have read the answer)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that cleaning this specific project doesn't work but cleaning all open project does the trick.

I leave this question if someone else get this issue.

Comment: Very strange, but that did it for me too.  Seems google needs to do some work on the plugin.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! Seems like there have been more issues since the update to the latest SDK.

Comment: Odd, exact same Behavior for me.  Updated to 8.0.1 ( win x64 ) and got aapt error, did a eclipse -clean and nothing, but doing a project->clean... fixed it.  Thanks!  Don't think I would have found this one without your suggestion.

Comment: Same issue on Mac Snow Leopard, clean of all projects did the trick.

Answer (score 17):

I found that this could be fixed by installing the ia32-libs package as the Android sdk requires 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Wouldn't have guessed that using 64bit was the problem if I hadn't seen your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I had to install the ia32-libs and then run a clean on the project.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem by adding a / after my android-sdk path in...

Eclipse->preferences->android->SDK Location:

Comment: i was hoping it was this simple!! ty.

Answer (score 12):

The aapt location has been changed recently. You can find it under:

/path/to/adt/sdk/buid-tools/android-[version]/aapt

Comment: Thanks! For me using the Android SDK installed by Android Studio it is found in `~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

In the terminal execute this command :

chmod a+x platform-tools/aapt

it solved the problem for me

(in 64bit you have to install ia32-libs with this command : sudo apt-get install ia32-libs)

Comment: you need to write your answer in understandable format. try to avoiding one line Answer and be formatted.

Comment: And where do we have to type this?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany `chmod +x /location/of/sdk/build-tools/your sdk version/aapt`

Answer (score 5):

- Check you have Android SDK version required installed and the path in Eclipse->preferences->android->SDK Location is correct.
- Check file permissions. Run:

  ```
  chmod a+x aapt
  ```
- If you are using Linux 64-bits. You'll see this hint:

  ```
  Hint: On 64-bit systems, make sure the 32-bit libraries are installed: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs        line 1  Android ADT Problem
  ```

  To fix it, you'll have to install 32-bits libraries:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lib32z1
  ```

  Maybe you'll need to install other libraries (libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386) or the emulator (libsdl1.2debian:i386). In my case it was enough installing libstdc++6

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
  ```

For more information you can check this question: 
[How to resolve Error executing aapt in Android/Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008169/how-to-resolve-error-executing-aapt-in-android-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you, my case. But please check the name of the library, its 'lib32z1'

Answer (score 2):

Starting build-tool 23, **aapt has been moved** under the ./bin directory

waiting for Eclipse ADT to be updated , one can just create a symbolic link to aapt

```
cd <path_to_your_android_sdk_folder>/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1
ln -s ./bin/aapt aapt
```

this will create a symlinc

```
<path_to_your_android_sdk_folder>/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/aapt
```

pointing to actual aapt tool laying here

```
<path_to_your_android_sdk_folder>/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/bin/aapt
```

and eclipse will be able to build android project back again :-)

Answer (score 1):

My issue with aapt got solved by simply chmod a+x platform-tools/aapt

Answer (score 1):

Following did the trick for me. Had to do the build dep as some of the lib dependencies were missing.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 
sudo apt-get build-dep lib32z1
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

Restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I didn't collide with this problem, but if you have ADT 8 revision or later, so you should read it's dependencies better: "ADT 8.0.0 is designed for use with SDK Tools r8. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r8 into your SDK, use the Android SDK and AVD Manager to do so." (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: I updated both but couldn't get it to work without the specific clean up of all projects

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem constantly and can not get R to be resolved to a variable after making projects clean, in addition to not being able to find aapt - 
Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at C:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\aapt.exe

None of the suggestions on this page make any sense or have helped in anyway. I'm using nothing but API 8 onwards.

Comment: Resolve this by opening the Android SDK and AVD manager. Have a look if anything has a broken link icon in the installed package list and regardless, to clear the errors, update all and check under available packages for everything from the Android repository and take all the google third party add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by checking 'build automatically' under project menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem after updating the SDK. I find out that the `AUTOGENERATE` folder doesn't have any file. What I done is :

`WINDOWS->ANDROID SDK MANAGER`:

1. rollback the SDK version to 16
2. Install all the tool provided.

   - SDK TOOLS (Version 16)
   - Platform Tools
3. install the SDK 4.0
4. Restart the eclipse

It solved!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that Eclipse 4.4 was looking for aapt without "bin/" at the end of the path.

Since I could not find a way to configure this path, I symlinked the aap executable from the "bin" subdirectory to the "23.0.0_rc1" directory one level higher. This works now.