# The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)

I am currently trying to develop an application for Android in the latest release of Eclipse. When I try to build and run, the following comes up:

```
[2011-02-17 17:08:03 - <ProgramName>] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2011-02-17 17:08:03 - <ProgramName>] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2011-02-17 17:08:03 - <ProgramName>] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\<sdk-directory>s\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

Now, I have updated the ADT plugin, I have the latest version of the Android SDK; adb.exe is, in fact, in the platform-tools directory and can be executed. I've tried everything I found on Google:

- I tried adb kill-server and adb start-server
- I tried to run it with an without an emulator started
- I have the given directory in my PATH (I tried with just the platform-tools in the path and I tried with having both platform-tools and tools in my PATH).

Notes: I am running Windows 7. Also, I have previously tested apps in Eclipse. This error is new to me since upgrading the SDK.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse? Sometimes my adb crashes (windows) and I get a "Program not responding" Error. Only solution for me is to restart eclipse

Comment: Yes. I have restarted it multiple times.

Comment: I just noticed that my SDK is not in the Program Files directory, that it is in my "Documents" directory. Could this be a cause of the problem?

Comment: Perhaps your antivirus has blocked `adb.exe`. Try to rename the folder you have installed the SDK. The next eclipse starts it will ask you where the SDK is.

Comment: I just cleaned my project and was good to go.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I just got the same problem and to fix it, I opened the task manager and killed the adb.exe process, then I restarted Eclipse.

Comment: Did it without even restarting Eclipse, just unplugged the phone and plugged it back in.

Comment: I tried everything until I saw this answer.  Just cleaning fixed the problem.  I'd give you a hundred upvotes if I could. thanks!

Comment: For those who can't run, even after restarting and cleaning. go to the /sdk/platform-tool/ via terminal, to make adb tool executable write `sudo chmod 777 adb`. It`s helped me, good luck.

Comment: I dont have that service runned on my system. why? :(

Answer (score 20):

Reinstall everything??? no way! just `add the path to SDK tools and platform tools in your classpath from Environment Variables.` Then restart Eclipse.

other way go to `Devices -> Reset adb`, or simply open the task manager and kill the `adb.exe` process.

Answer (score 15):

I restarted eclipse and did the **Project** -> **Clean** -> select your project
One of them fixed my problem with adb

```
[2011-12-31 10:50:45 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!                      good

[2011-12-31 10:50:45 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.             good

[2011-12-31 10:50:45 - HelloAndroid] Could not find HelloAndroid.apk!     bad
```

Thanks for the help.  On to the next problem (sigh)

Comment: That worked for me too!

Answer (score 7):

Sounds a bit familiar with my problem: [aapt not found under the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386392/aapt-not-found-under-the-right-path)

I needed to clean *all* open projects to get it working again...

Comment: By clean, do you mean right clicking on the project, going to "Source" and clicking "Clean up..."?

Comment: no, I mean Project -> Clean -> select your project

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem with you. And after two days wondering why this occurs to me, I finally got through this by moving the adb.exe from the unreliable software list of the COMODO anti-virus to its reliable software list. At that time, I had tried at least 5 kinds of measures to make the adb work, including all above...

Comment: solve the problem for me 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured

Comment: Thanks for the COMODO tip. What worked for me was from COMODO -> Defence+ -> ViewActiveProcessList right click on adb.exe and emulator-arm.exe and select "Add to Trusted Files". Then kill those processes and restart eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with adb.exe and Eclipse last time I updated ADT plugin. The solution was to run Eclipse as administrator and reinstall ADT.

Comment: Okay, so I shut down Eclipse and then ran it as administrator. I uninstalled the ADT, and then re-installed it. Still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be with your firewall or antivirus.

1. Disable all network connection
2. Disable firewall
3. Disable Antivirus

Make *sure* they all disabled.

Run your script in Eclipse.  If it works, then 2 and 3 might be the culprit. For me, it was comodo firewall.  I  created a filter for Adb.exe

Answer (score 1):

For me the following worked:

1. Kill adb.exe from Task Manager
2. Restart Eclipse as administrator
3. For my app, the target was Google APIs level 10.. I went to Window-> AVD Manager and the entry for "Google APIs level 10" had a broken instead of a green tick - so I just clicked the entry and clicked the "repair" button and problem was fixed

(It was probably only 3 above..)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you've posted, and assuming it's not a typo, Eclipse is looking in **C:\s\platform-tools...**

If that's the case, then you should check Eclipse's Window/Preferences/Android option for the SDK Location. Maybe yours is set to **"C:\s"**. You can't edit it to be a value such as that without causing an error, but maybe it's got corrupted somehow.

Comment: The SDK location is pointing to the root of my SDK on my device. 

I tried to edit it to see if setting it to the platform-tools location would work, but it would not allow me (as I expected). However, the error message stated: 

    "_Could not find folder 'tools' inside...[directory]_"

Is it suppose to say tools? Or something else? Thanks!

Comment: @NickT: Eclipse does not have issues finding the android SDK if you point it to the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.

```
[2011-12-19 11:45:09 - RayhReport] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2011-12-19 11:45:09 - RayhReport] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

When you go to `D:\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe` path then you see the text file,the name of file is "adb_has_moved" thats means your `adb.exe` is moved to platform-tools copied down the adb.exe and paste in tools folder and run it. I'm sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to get this error if you are running the test project using JUnit instead of Android JUnit. Naturally, the solution is just to change how you run it.