# The connection to adb is down

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run an android application I build in the android emulator using eclipse , but every time I try I get the following error:

```
[2013-11-30 14:14:12 - MyFirstApp] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2013-11-30 14:14:12 - MyFirstApp] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2013-11-30 14:14:12 - MyFirstApp] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\<sdk directory>' and can be executed.
```

I tried adb kill-server and adb start-server, searched Stack Overflow , found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035456/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occurred)
 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-sever-error-has-occured), tried everything , but still can't get to start the application.
The AVD starts but the app doesn't start on AVD.

Then after some waiting,

```
[2013-11-30 14:26:54 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
```

Comment: turn off your firewall and try again maybe its worked

Comment: tried that too , still nothing.

Comment: Finally able to run the app , I had to restart the pc to make it work , don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your error it self saying :You must restart adb and Eclipse.

Try this once:

Step1. Go to DDMS perspective

Step2. Click on emulator opened at Devices tab

Step3. Click view Menu on reset adb as shown bellow image

Step4. Restart Eclipse.

[image]

May it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your Eclipse and device or emulator which you are using for testing apps and go to task manager find adb.exe -> End Task.
You will not find any error after that.