# My genymotion cant connect ecplise sometime

Tags: android, eclipse

Log:

> [2015-04-19 08:29:33 - HealthAssistant] ------------------------------
>
> [2015-04-19 08:29:33 - HealthAssistant] Android Launch!
>
> [2015-04-19 08:29:33 - HealthAssistant] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
>
> [2015-04-19 08:29:33 - HealthAssistant] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
>
> [2015-04-19 08:29:33 - HealthAssistant] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.

I have already configurated adb.exe to my computer path,
and I try to use adb kill-sever and start-sever,but it doesnt work.

Comment: Is it not the same question:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035456/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occurred?rq=1
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured