# Problme running ADT eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android development. As per the developers website of android I downloaded ADT Bundle and setup as per the instructions on the site.
I am able to open eclipse and sdk manager. However when I tried to open a sample application I face error saying

```
aapt.exe has stopped working
```

and I see some errors in the java files. It is not able to find some support packages at the import. I checked the SDK and its path which is right. What may be the error?
Also I can see only platform 19. How can I get other platforms if I need to? SDK manager doesn't show any uninstalled platforms or tools.

Any help appreciated.

When I start the SDK manager it loads few packages and then gives error saying "Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com" & "Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com".  I dont understand what is it. I am not writing any code as of now. Simply followed the steps to install and run eclipse from adt bundle and then imported a sampleapp from it only.

Comment: please paste some code for better understanding

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: are you install java jdk.

Comment: Edited for further information

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831707/1237656). This issue sometimes comes with the platform-tools.