# "error 402: Current Android sdk version doesn't support initialWindow as xml tag" despite SDK 23

Tags: android, xml, air, landscape

I have an old Adobe AIR app that is working just fine on Android, except that it comes out in portrait mode.  Without changing the source, just the application descriptor, I would like to fix this.  Currently I have:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">
...
<android>
   <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[
          <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal">
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
              <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
              <application android:enabled="true">
...
```

Now, if I add this:

```
                  <initialWindow>
                    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
                  </initialWindow>
```

...within the inner `<application>` tag, ADT says:

```
application.xml: error 402: Current Android sdk version doesn't support initialWindow as xml tag
```

I tried changing the AIR version (yes, see AIR vs Android below) up to 3.9 with no difference.

If I put it within only the outer `<application>` I get this error instead:

```
application.xml(24): error 103: application.initialWindow is an unexpected element/attribute
```

So I'm guessing I have it in the right spot, but I need to add a version number.

However, after a bit of searching, I could not find documented anywhere which Android SDK version I would need to specify (using ["the -platformsdk flag in the ADT command if the element was introduced after Android 2.2"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSBE9908A0-8E3A-4329-8ABD-12F2A19AB5E9.html)).

## AIR vs Android

This `<initialWindow>` thing isn't actually an Android XML tag, but an Adobe XML tag, contrary to [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f33105f2a1293d3d21e0-7ffe) which says that child elements of the `<manifest>` tag are "Defined by the Android SDK."  (Search for `<initialWindow>` and you'll find only Adobe AIR docs, not Android SDK docs.  Which is too bad, because the latter are pretty good at telling you exactly which version an element was introduced in.)

## Update 1: SDK 23.0.1 isn't new enough?

I added the `-platformsdk` option pointing to the Android SDK, which then complained about missing aadt.exe.  Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831707 I copied in that from 23.0.1 under build-tools.  I still get the same message.  I also tried adding within the `<manifest>` tag `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`, still the same result.

## UPDATE 2: Compiled AndroidManifest.xml has lower Android SDK version!

Using `aapt` from the Android SDK, I found out that the AIR-made APK, despite the above line in Update 1, contains this:

```
E: uses-sdk (line=48)
  A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x9
  A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x13
```

## Update 3: Also true with AIR SDK 19

Although with this difference:

```
  A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x17
  A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x17
```

Interestingly with SDK 19, the screen orientation is now also defined:

```
    A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x2
```

...but of course I want 0 (landscape), not 0x2 (user).

Comment: FWIW this also occurs (with the tagname changed in the error message) if I try to use the `<autoOrients>` tag in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work

```
    <android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

I have not used Adobe air,this is just a suggestion

Comment: This is prohibited by AIR, unfortunately: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f33105f2a1293d3d21e0-7ffd

Comment: If you try it anyway (whether on the application element, as the Adobe docs say, or the activity element, as the Android docs say), you get `error 404: Android attribute android:screenOrientation is not allowed to be overridden`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the initialWindow tag goes within the outermost application tag, as the docs say.  At one point I had tried this and gotten an error, but I guess it was a coincidence with something else I was trying.  I can confirm this fixes it on AIR 2.6, 3.9, and 19.