# How to resolve Error executing aapt in Android/Eclipse?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

Error executing aapt.

```
Please check aapt is present at /home/padmakumar/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt    NhpAndroid_tablet_k4        line 1  Android ADT Problem

Hint: On 64-bit systems, 
make sure the 32-bit libraries are installed: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs    
        line 1  Android ADT Problem
```

I can delete 2 errors in problem tab for temp solution or cleaning the projects or deleting the gen/bin folder and recreating or restarting works fine for temporary.

how to resolve permanently to aviod this problem? any help?

Note: I executed this command '*sudo apt-get install ia32-libs*' still its asking.

Comment: for resolving this I am restarting m eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try these commands line

`sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386`

for running the emulator you need that additional package:

`sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386`

then on Ubuntu pre-14-04:

`apt-get install ia32-libs`

On Ubuntu 14.04 use the [following commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307732) to install ia32-libs:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
exit
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your description whether it is an Eclipse or Android SDK problem.
Try running aapt directly from the console (gives usage help) and check out the required libraries with `ldd aapt`. Ldd output looks something like following:

```
.../android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools$ ldd aapt
   linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7712000)
   librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf76b8000)
   libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf769e000)
   libz.so.1 => /lib32/libz.so.1 (0xf7689000)
   libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf759a000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7574000)
   libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7559000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf73fd000)
   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76f6000)
```

Notice that although the system is 64-bit aapt links in 32-bit libraries. This is what the ia32-libs package is for. So if you find appt runs fine on the commandline it must be an Eclipse problem.

Comment: for me its showing like                                                      /android-sdk/platform-tools$ ldd aapt
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf772e000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf7703000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76ea000)
 libz.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libz.so.1 (0xf76d4000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75de000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf75b8000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7599000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf743f000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf772f000)

Answer (score 0):

What It worked for me is installing "multiarch-support" package from Synaptic (Ubuntu). Then clean your project from Eclipse.