# Android aapt can not be found on Mac

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea

I am getting the following error when trying to compile my android project in IntelliJ (v11.1) on MacOSX.

---

```
I/O error: Cannot run program "/%PATH_TO_SDK%/android-sdk-macosx/platforms
/android-16/tools/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

---

Some places say it is saying I might be using a 64 bit version of the libraries when I need 32 bit but everyone experiencing that problem is using Ubuntu so the solutions I have found are only suited to that.

The weird thing is, it worked this morning when I only had android-16 installed, but after I downloaded the other versions it stopped.

Any help would be appreciated.  Can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Ye, I did try that before posting lol

Comment: Is Platform tools SDK package installed? Actually 'aapt' tool should be located in <sdk>/platform-tools directory. Does it exist there? IDEA tries to find it in <sdk>/platforms/<platform>/tools if it cannot be found in <sdk>/platform-tools folder

Comment: It is looking in the wrong place, aapt is in platform-tools as it should be. After restating IntelliJ another 5 times it worked somehow.  Doesn't make any sense, NOTHING was changed.  Thanks ekudel for your assistance - post a response and I'll give you the tick!

Comment: How to resolve Error executing aapt in Android/Eclipse?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8008169/1012284

Comment: I do not have aapt in my platform-tools...

Answer (score 19):

aapt location has been changed and it can be found at

```
/path/to/adt/sdk/buid-tools/android-[version]/aapt
```

credits to [rafalmanka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2373380/rafalmanka)

more info: [aapt not found under the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386392/aapt-not-found-under-the-right-path)

Answer (score 13):

On MacOS with default Android installation, the current `aapt` location is inside specific build-tools version. For build-tools `28.0.3`, you will find it in the following path:

```
/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3
```

Remember to change `userName` to your username in MacOS.