# R.java lost file after import

Tags: android, r.java-file

After importing the project file disappeared R.java I tried Project - Clean, nothing ...

[image]

Comment: Did you notify what errors are there in your xml files?

Comment: 1 Answer is imitated in 15 ways.Should try to improve Others Answer rather than saying the same thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you've any errors on your `*.xml` files. The `R.java` file will not generate. Try to clear that errors first. After, clean your project and try to run.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project` and hit `Clean`. This should, among others, regenerate your R.java file.
OR there might be any error in one of XML files.

Answer (score 2):

//once you import your project. your library jar files wont get import it seems.

try to put that libs in project from **C:/user/musanin/ and D:/java/work_Max**

Answer (score 2):

Clear all errors from the "res" folder and clean. It will generate your R.java file.

Answer (score 2):

That implies errors on the layout or Manifest file , which are XML . Fix them first and clean the project

Answer (score 2):

Without Removing the error present in .xml file your R would not appear..Open your .xml file and see what the errors are..If they are false error then just format the .xml file [ctrl+shift+f this will format your file] and save it. Then Clean your project and buil it again..You will get your R.java back.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rectify the errors in the xml files and after that do

1) clean the project `(or)`

2) Restart the eclipse

Comment: Opinion 2 goes wrong my dear.Eclipse will not create problem in R.java file

Comment: sorry i forgot to place after in line1.

Comment: for resolving this I am restarting m eclipse. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8008169/1012284

Answer (score 0):

I lost the R files once importing the project. The reason was target SDK conflict (in .manifest file) between appcompat library and my project (my project had 19 whereas appcompat was 21).

- Change the project's android:targetSdkVersion into that of appcompat library project.
- Clean the project.

And you should be good to go.