# Android Processing does not build program

Tags: linux, mobile, build, ide

I'm having issues with Processing, and IDE for Android Development. I'm running Linux.

The problem report is the following: "Error from inside Android tools, check the console"

And this is what appears:

```
 BUILD FAILED
 /home/user/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649:
 The following error occurred while executing this line:
 /home/user/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:690:
 Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
 "/home/user/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/build-tools/android-4.3/aapt"
 (in directory "/tmp/android1536856872512874187sketch"):
 java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory    at
 java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)    at
 java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)   at
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)   at
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)    at
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:699)  at
 org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)  at
 org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at
 org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at
 org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
 org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)   at
 org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)  at
 org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    at
 processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.antBuild(AndroidBuild.java:415)
    at processing.mode.android.AndroidBuild.build(AndroidBuild.java:73)
    at
 processing.mode.android.AndroidMode.handleRunDevice(AndroidMode.java:220)
    at
 processing.mode.android.AndroidEditor$14.run(AndroidEditor.java:310)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such
 file or directory  at
 java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)     at
 java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)   at
 java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)    ... 44 more

 Total time: 0 seconds
```

I would really love some help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using 64-bit version of SDK on a 64 bit Linux.

I found some build tools binaries are 32-bit executables, so based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812121/2229409) answer the solution that worked for me was to install ia32-libs package.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```