# Bash cannot find adb even though it's definitely there

Tags: android, linux, adb

I'm running ArchLinux, kernel 3.4.4, bash version 4.2.29. I downloaded the android sdk from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Once extracted I did, did `~/android-sdk-linux/tools/android` and installed the SDK platform tools package.

From there I tried the following:

```
> ls -l ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mediocregopher mediocregopher 204436 Jun 28 13:20 /home/mediocregopher/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb

> file ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb 
/home/mediocregopher/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped

> ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb 
bash: /home/mediocregopher/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
```

Clearly the file is there and at the very least executable, why can't bash seem to find it? I've tried adding the platform-tools folder to my path as well as sudo and su-ing, but no matter what it seems like the file is not found. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're running on a 64bit system and you do not have the 32bit compatibility libraries installed.

The error is actually coming from the fact that it can't find the 32bit `ld.so`.

If you're using ubuntu/debian, I think you just need to `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` and it should work.

Comment: +1 This is the far less common reason for ENOENT from an [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: This ended up being the problem. I had found android-sdk in arch's AUR but couldn't get it to install because it needed a bunch of lib32-* packages. Turns out I just needed to enable the multilib repo. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: [Installing the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) explains this under "Troubleshooting Ubuntu."

Answer (score 9):

For 'modern' versions of Ubuntu (13.10 and higher), the accepted answer is not working anymore: They removed the '32 bit compability libraries' and instead you need to use multiarch packages that happily coexists next to each other. See [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package) on AskUbuntu.

Instead you need to install the 32 bit version of `libc`:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Next, I encounterd that a 32 bit version of `libstdc++` is also required by `adb`:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

Now `adb` should be working (again).

[Android SDK on a 64-bit linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710499/android-sdk-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine) shows that some other libraries are required as well. I did not seem to require them as well, but might have had them installed already.

Comment: +1, This solution also helped me install Anaconda 32bit on a 64bit system