# download android emulator all version in windows

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

Is there any possible way to install Android Emulator itself on the windows. I would need that for the Testing purpose? Any Idea?

I dont want to install whole sdk. i just want install the Emulater itself. that emulator is just like that a phone for the testing purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to download the SDK components individually, (why someone would want to do what, I don't know, but anyways..) here is the links to the Tools, Docs, Samples and APIs.

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.1_r1-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.1_r1-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.1_r1-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.5_r04-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.5_r04-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.5_r04-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0_r01-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0_r01-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0.1_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0.1_r01-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.0.1_r01-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.1_r03-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.2_r03-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.3.1_r02-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.0_r02-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.1_r03-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-3.2_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-14_r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-15_r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-16_r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-14_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-15_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-16_r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.1_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.2_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.3_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-3.0_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-3.1_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-3.2_r01-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-14_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-15_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/samples-16_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r14-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r14-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r14-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r15_rc9-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r15_rc9-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r15_rc9-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20.0.3-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20.0.3-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20.0.3-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r21_rc10-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r21_rc10-linux.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r21_rc10-macosx.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-16_r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-14_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-15_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-16_r02.zip

**Google APIs**:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-3-r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-4_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-5_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-6_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-7_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-8_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-9_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-10_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-11_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-12_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-13_r01.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-14_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-15_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-16_r03.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_tv-12_r02.zip

**Extras**

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r10.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/market_licensing-r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/market_apk_expansion-r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_1013.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/usb_driver_r07-windows.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/market_billing_r02.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/googleadmobadssdkandroid-6.2.1.zip
https://dl.google.com/gaformobileapps/GoogleAnalyticsAndroid_1.4.2.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/webdriver_r02.zip
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/gcm_r03.zip

Comment: it is installed via sdk only know.but i wish to install the emulator w/o install android sdk

Comment: I don't get it, why? If you don't wanna install it via the SDK Manager, then the only option is to manually download the zipfiles and   try by trial-and-error to see what zips you need to get a working set of tools and system images.

Comment: Thanks for these. I can install these by executing `tools/android` and making sdcard with `tools/mksdcard` and installing 32libs(if x64) at https://askubuntu.com/a/504492/964180

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to use Android in PC for experiencing something, but not for developing apps.

Here are the steps to do so

For installing Android 4.1(16) emulator
Download SDK Tools Revision 19 from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r19-linux.zip which may support upto Android Jelly Bean.
Decompress it.
Download emulator from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-16_r03.zip
It does not contain images of system, data, etc.,
Download armv7 system.img from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sysimg_armv7a-16_r03.zip
Decompress it in system-images/android-16/default folder. It should look like system-images/android-16/default/armeabi-v7a.
-Install ia32-libs if are using 64bit PC.(Ref:- [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/504492/964180), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473415/11620356)

```sh
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6:i386
sudo apt install ia32-libs #or sudo apt install lib32z1
```

-Execute tools/android
-`Android SDK Manager` window will open
-In this wizard choose `Tools` menu and select `Manage AVDs...`
-`Android Virtual Device Manager` window will open
-Select `New...`
-Give a Name and select `Android 4.1.2 - API Level 16` as `Target`
-Give a `Size` to sdcard.
-Create AVD
-Slect AVD in list and click on `Start...`
-Enjoy!

If you want to add more emulators like Android [2.2](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.2_r03-linux.zip), [1.6](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r03-linux.zip) etc, then place the platform-images.zip in platforms/ folder and add new emulators in existing sdk(here 4.1.2).

More Links for system-images and others can be found at [How do I download the Android SDK without downloading Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37505709/11620356)

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-tools.html?m=1

https://android-development-tools-offline.blogspot.com/?m=1

https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net