# How to install Android Studio with SDK tools in 32 bit Windows 7

Tags: android

I have downloaded two files from their website. Both file are archived file and i have extracted both of them one file is sdk tools and other is androidstudio ide. But i don't know how to install android studio with SDK tools.

Comment: You use Android Studio to get the other tools, not the other way around

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-android-studio#answer-43118880

Answer (score 0):

Once you installed Android Studio launch it :

1. You already started a project then hit this button in the top bar
   [image]
2. You didn't started a project then click on the button **configure** at
   the bottom right of the window and click on **Android SDK Manager**

A new window will pop up, there is an **SDK Tools** section where you can choose which tool to install.