# Unable to find the path to locate android SDK in D drive with genymotion

Tags: android, sdk, genymotion

I have installed genymotion but I need external SDK to debug my code. **I want to download SDK for android 4.1 without download Android Studio.** This is my steps which I follow the method [How do I download the Android SDK without downloading Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-android-studio) by Tom:

1.download zip file from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip

2.extract the folder and locate it at D:/sdk-tools/

3.refer to this link https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html , I use command D:/sdk-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-16" to install SDK

4.It downloaded, but can't find any SDK when I use genymotion, adb to locate the SDK. 
[image]
[image]

5. Since, some said it have to installed in C drive, I check the path C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android but also can't find any SDK.

I need to have the SDK in D drive as my C drive is running out of space. I want to use genymotion to debug my ionic code.

I have adb.exe in genymotion directory but not in D:/sdk-tools directory.

Which part of my steps is/are incorrect? Please advice.

**EDIT:**
I have downloaded and extract the platform-tools inside D:/sdk-tools directory. Here  is the link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried entering `D:/sdk-tools` instead of the full path?