# Ionic can not add android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to uninstal cordova then instal again but still not working

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
    information.
```

Comment: Hello Sakotic. Welcome. Can you try to run the same line with --verbose at the end and tell us the result? It may help to find out what happened :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install your android SDK/build tools. 
You can do it manually or using your android studio installation if exists.
To do it with Android Studio you can:

1. Go to settings->Appearance and Behavior->Android SDK
2. Go to the SDK Platforms tab and select the latest Android SDK
   package.
3. Go to the SDK Toos tab and select the following checkboxes:

   - Android SDK Build-Tools
   - Android SDK Platform-Tools
   - Android SDK Tools
   - NDK
   - Android Support Repository
   - Google Repository
4. Apply and accept

To do it without using Android Studio there's an answered question here: [How do I download the Android SDK without downloading Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-android-studio)

Comment: I try  --verbose  it shows nothing  then I uninstall ionic and then install globally then I uninstall Cordova and install again  then finally I add android  but now I have problem to  build Apk  file  with ionic cordova build