# How to download Android SDK without Visual Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've read this thread [How do I download the Android SDK without downloading Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-android-studio). I've done the steps in the 2nd answer, but I get an error (that someone also posted in a comment)

> $ ./sdkmanager "platforms;android-29" Warning: Could not create settings java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57) at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)

User Hydroproper replied saying

> @mcandre Passing --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} or --sdk_root=%ANDROID_HOME% (Batch) resolves the error here

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with what he's saying to do, and I don't have enough Karma to ask him (4 away). Anybody know how to do as he says? (Pass --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME}). Thanks! (Or maybe I could get 4 upvotes so I can ask him)

Edit: It appears he's saying when you run the command to add that --sdk_root part into the command. Unfortunately, immediately when I open the SDK Manager it gives this error and exits. Is there somewhere I can add this argument to the batch file you think?

Answer (score 0):

Well I re-downloaded the Command Line Interface and ran the SDK Manager and that error didn't appear anymore, so I'm thinking the download was just corrupt. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all direct Android SDK download link via the file https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-2.xml

Search this XML file for `Android SDK platform 29`
Now you can combine the `<url>` value with the repo-link and download directly the SDK from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-29_r05.zip without any tools.