# Fixing android sdk setup for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After opening andrioid studio for first use, I see the following:
[image: select SDK prompt]

d.android.com/sdk however redirects to a different page with downloads without the android sdk. So I am not able to download it.

Trying to install android-sdk with apt (Ubuntu 18.04) results in problems with the android licenses that I can not resolve, so I uninstalled (with --purge) it again.

I have tried re-installing android studio multiple times in different ways.

How can I setup my android-sdk properly?

Comment: You need to download the android sdk. Save it in your hard-drive and set its path in android studio.

Comment: I want to, as I mentioned android sdk is not listed on the page where it is supposed to be available.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Can you provide a pic about what it shows when you click install sdk from android studio?

Comment: I have added a screenshot with the prompt. I cannot click 'install sdk', I can go to d.android.com/sdk which redirects to a page without the sdk.

Comment: Reinstall it. You'll get an option to download to sdk there..

Comment: I have already reinstalled it, it shows the same prompt every time.

Comment: Maybe this will help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-android-studio

Comment: I figured it out using that post, thanks! I will do a full write up of all the steps I had to take to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full sdk start out by downloading the [command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools).
After extracting this file you are left with a tools folder.

Place the tools folder inside a new folder called `cmdline-tools`.
This is necessary to avoid namespace issues.

In a terminal inside cmdline-tools run the following (replace 27 with the min version you want your app to be compatible with):

```
./tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
./tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools"
./tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
./tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

At the same folder level as cmdline-tools you should now have the folders:

- build-tools
- tools
- platforms
- emulator
- licenses
- patcher

Move all these folders to a folder named Android in your home dir.
For the sdk prompt in android studio select this folder.