# How create android emulator without android studio?

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.2. 
I create 2 emulators by Android Studio. Nice.
But the question is:

Is it possible to create android emulator WITHOUT Android Studio?

Our QA need to use emulators for test our applications. But it not need Android Studio.

How QA can create android emulator without Android Studio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563126/11620356

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of 3th party emulators out there, which are quite easy to use and fast to set up. Just have a quick look in your favorite search engine. But here is a short list of better known ones:

- BlueStacks
- Genymotion
- Nox App Player
- MeMu
- ARChon
- KoPlayer

They should all be able to run your app on a pc to show someone. Have a look on them and inform yourself about the licensing and features.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Download Java JDK from the following link and install: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

2 - Download the Android SDK from the following link and install: https://android-sdk.uptodown.com/windows/descargar

3 - Download Intel HAXM from the following link and install: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

4 - Start the SDK Manager, install the tools and platforms you need.

5 - Start AVD Manager and create new emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can setup Android Emulator without installing Android Studio. We have to download **commandline-tools** and use **sdkmanager**, **avdmanager**, **emulator** tools to make an emulator and run it.

Ref:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65537217/11620356
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563126/11620356