# Install Android emulator without installing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just want to set android emulator without studio-ide and use it like a mobile and tweak it.

I have downloaded command-line tools from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip

Unzipped in folder `$HOME/AndroidSDK`.

I just want to run some emulators.

Then ran below

```sh
cd ~/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools/bin
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$HOME/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools --list --include_obsolete --verbose
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$HOME/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools --verbose "emulator" "platforms;android-25" "system-images;android-25;default;arm64-v8a" "platform-tools"
./sdkmanager --sdk_root=$HOME/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools --licenses
./avdmanager -v create avd -n Nougat -k "system-images;android-25;default;arm64-v8a"
```

I got below error when creating avd.

```
Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository...
null
```

It is related to [How create android emulator without android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53884511/11620356)
But I can't find proper solution to my problem.

Where it is going wrong?

**Ref:-**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59907256/11620356
- https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line
- https://dev.to/koscheyscrag/how-to-install-android-emulator-without-installing-android-studio-3lce
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176718/11620356
- [How do I download the Android SDK without downloading Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37505709/11620356)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

Where I made wrong is, decompressing to wrong directory and using wrong --sdk_root.
As said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176718/11620356), I have to create a dir called `cmdline-tools` and decompress in it. Now we will have another cmdline-tools dir. We have to rename it to the respective commandline tool version we are using. In my case it is 3.0.

Finally my script should be look like below.

```sh
mkdir -p ~/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools
cd ~/AndroidSDK/cmdline-tools
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6858069_latest.zip -o tools.zip
unzip -q tools.zip
mv cmdline-tools 3.0
cd 3.0/bin
./sdkmanager --list --include_obsolete --verbose
./sdkmanager --verbose "emulator" "system-images;android-25;default;x86_64" "platforms;android-25" "platform-tools"
./sdkmanager --licenses
./avdmanager -v create avd -n Nougat -k "system-images;android-25;default;x86_64"
../../../emulator/emulator -avd Nougat
```

See https://github.com/HemanthJabalpuri/AndroidEmulator_without_Studio for more info.

Comment: Now I have new issue, above commands are for reference to me. Actually I didn't tested those. After I am executing avdmanager I got error with OpenJDK11 class `com.android.sdklib.repository.generated.repository.v1.PlatformDetailsType cannot be cast to class com.android.sdklib.repository.meta.DetailsTypes$SysImgDetailsType (com.android.sdklib.repository.generated.repository.v1.PlatformDetailsType and com.android.sdklib.repository.meta.DetailsTypes$SysImgDetailsType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`. I tried with **JDK8** and one **JRE8** in AndroidStudio too. But same error repeats.

Comment: This seems like it only appears when I install android versions that does not have separate system-image folders.