# Compile Android project on linux, cannot find aapt

Tags: android

Although the file `aapt` is absolutely at its location, I still get this error when trying to compile my project:

```
|=> //apps/myapp:debug_keystore...  0.0s (checking local cache)
|=> //apps/myapp:app#aapt_package...  0.0s (checking local cache)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/adminuser/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt" (in directory "/home/adminuser/my-project"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: What happens when you try to execute it from the command line? I think it is missing some library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a problem of running the android sdk on a 64 bit linux machine without required 32 bit libraries.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473415/1309964 for a actual list.